# Error in downloading photo into ios app from amazon aws s3 bucket

Tags: swift, xcode, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am developing and ios app and am new to using amazon s3 bucket, and I am using it store photos, however when I try to download the photo from the storage bucket onto an image view in my app it outputs "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSServiceErrorDomain error 11.)" in the console.

I have looked around online and people have similar problems but have not found any solutions to the problem.

```
func getPicture(){
        let downloadedFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("test.png")
        let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
        if let downloadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest(){
            downloadRequest.bucket = bucket
            downloadRequest.key = currentQuestionData?._userId!
            downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL = downloadedFile
                transferManager.download(downloadRequest).continueWith(block: { (task: AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in
                    if( task.error != nil){
                        print(task.error!.localizedDescription)
                        print(self.currentQuestionData!._userId)
                        return nil
                    }

                    print(task.result!)

                    if let data = NSData(contentsOf: downloadedFile){
                        print("getting image")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                            self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
                        })
                    }
                    return nil
                })
        }
    }
```

It should load the image on to the imageView but instead it gives the error "The operation couldn’t be completed (com.amazonaws.AWSServiceErrorDomain error 11.)"

Comment: you may not have access to the resource. check the policy. Also don't forget to set your AWSServiceConfiguration with the your credentials.

Comment: Thank you I think that is the issue